# How do I use the python continue keyword as a string literal in a python script?

Tags: python, keyword, interpreter, continue

I'm writing a python script wherein I need to use the *continue* word.

I know that it is a python keyword.

So how should I write my script so that python will not complain that I am using a keyword as a string literal.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: that's not a thing anyone would recommend.

Comment: Did you try using quotes?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Will try and let you know

Comment: uuhh that's what you meant

Comment: A string literal or a variable name? Use `'continue'` for the former? For variable names, just choose something different.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Single quotes did not work. Getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Your answer did not work. Your elitist reputation is getting spoilt. Too bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like:
`_continue`

But why not using more descriptive and longer variable name?! like:
`continue_whatever` or `go_on` ...

Answer (score 0):

The normal practice is to use a trailing underscore to use a keyword that already being used by the language, like `continue_` or `input_`.

I don't think anyone would think that just overwriting keywords is every a good idea.

Comment: I am constrained to use the continue keyword since I am invoking another python script (Not written by me or in my control) that makes use of the 'continue' word as one of its arguments

Comment: how does that force you to use continue in a way that would cause problems with the keyword?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `fooo(continue=whatever)` should not cause the interpreter to complain

Comment: I am writing my python script in visual studio code and editor colors it and recognizes it as a keyword with other keywords like with, for, import etc

Comment: That's an argument, not a string literal.

Comment: @HamzaAhmedZia Editors are often do not implement the full language’s grammar, so they may incorrectly show keywords as special even though they appear in places where they are not recognized. Just run the script and see if it works.

Comment: also, there shouldn't ever be a problem using continue in a string litteral